# how can i render rails code from a store HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I have a Page model which has a body property in which the following in stored as example:

```
<h1>This is the HTML body</h1>
<p>and we want to use some rails code </p>

<%= Time.current.to_s %>
```

In my controller I get this page and render it simple in my view like this

```
 -- rest omitted to keep it clear
    <div class="card-body">
      <%= @post.body.html_safe %>

    </div>
```

How can I make the rails part `<%= Time.current.to_s %>` to render into displaying the date?

Comment: May be, you can use a parser to find rails code `<%= %>`, and run it with `eval`.
It is really `very bad idea`. You can run any `malicious code` this way.
Why don't you execute your `@post.body` before you save, so you can directly print html later.

Comment: I have another solution, if you want to replace few possible ruby code, you can use `gsub` for each scenario. `@post.body.gsub('<%= Time.current.to_s %>', Time.current.to_s)`. Does it works?

Comment: How about `<%= ERB.new(@post.body.html_safe) %>`?